# Why is the execution not entering the loop while reading the .csv file?

Tags: python, function, loops, csv, for-loop

I am having a problem while reading a .csv file.

```
def isPresent(self, stid):
    with open('D:\First_Sem_Project\Student\Student.csv', 'r', newline='') as file1:
        reader = csv.reader(file1)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0]==stid:
               return 1
    file1.close()
    return 0
```

The condition row[0]==stid is not being executed. I also tried putting a print statement just after the for-loop signature, but nothing is being printed. Please help me out.

Comment: What does stid look like? Also you're saying this always returns 0 and doesn't enter the for loop at all?

Comment: stid(Student ID) is a string value. It is checking if stid is identical to the first element of a row of the .csv file.  Yes, it is not entering the loop

Comment: The first thing I would try is replace the if statement with print(row) and see what that returns to get an idea of the shape of your file. And even though the answer that one person gave was rude and uncalled for, I do think depending on your use case, using pandas might make this a bit easier.

Comment: How do you call `isPresent()` and what's the content like in the `student.csv`?

Comment: Please provide a [MRE]. Remember that we only have as much context as you provide in your question, so showing us code that does not reproduce your problem _on its own_ doesn't help us help you

Comment: 1) You don't need `file1.close()`, the `with` context manager will automatically close the file. 2) It would seem this `row[0]==stid` is never `True`. So the `stid` value is not found in that column. That could be because `stid` is not actually in that column, you are looking in the wrong column or the form of the value in `stid` and in the column are subtly different.